# How to convert pandas column to numeric if there are strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that has numerical values, empty values and text values. I want to do the following in pandas:

1. Numerical Values -> Float
2. Empty Values -> N/A
3. Text Values -> N/A

When I try to run `astype('float')`, I get an error:

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['5', '4', '3', '', 'NO DATA ', '5']
data = ['5', '4', '3', '', '', '5']
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data})

df[['data']].astype('float')
```

I've tried to look over the documentation and stackoverflow, but I didn't find out how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Using panda's `to_numeric` function, we can turn any valid value into floats, while turning invalid values into NaNs:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = ['5', '4', '3', 'NO DATA', '', '5']
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data})

df['data'] = pd.to_numeric(df['data'], errors='coerce')
```

The `errors='coerce'` makes sure that invalid values are turned into NaN instead of raising an error.

And the result will be:

```py
data
0   5.0
1   4.0
2   3.0
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   5.0
```

Comment: Questions like this have been asked many times, and new ones should be closed as duplicates of the originals.